# How handle data with varying number of items for one column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out what is the most elegant way of handling data where I have a varying number of values for the same column, for example different numbers of tags for images:

```
image.id <- c("img1", "img2", "img3")
image.tags <- c("house#garden#sky#tree", "house#garden#lake", "house#tree")
image.data <- data.frame(image.id, image.tags)
```

The goal is to be able to locate the rows that contain the tag "tree", for example. My next step would be to strsplit() the tags into single tags, but then I'm not sure where to put the result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

**1) grepl** We could just grep out the trees:

```
subset(image.data, grepl("tree", image.tags))
##   image.id            image.tags
## 1     img1 house#garden#sky#tree
## 3     img3            house#tree
```

**2) nesting** Another possiblity is to base it on the fact that a data.frame column can be a list of vectors, one vector for each row.  Here `DF` is such a data.frame and we can look for `"tree"` in each such vector:

```
DF <- transform(image.data, image.tags = strsplit(as.character(image.tags), "#"))
subset(DF, sapply(image.tags, function(x) "tree" %in% x))
##       image.id               image.tags
## 1     img1 house, garden, sky, tree
## 3     img3              house, tree
```

**3) long form** Yet another possiblity is to convert to long form:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

image.data %>%
   separate_rows(image.tags) %>% # long form
   filter(image.tags == "tree")
##   image.id image.tags
## 1     img1       tree
## 2     img3       tree
```

or perhaps what is wanted is to list all rows of those groups containing a tree:

```
image.data %>%
   separate_rows(image.tags) %>% # long form
   right_join(filter(., image.tags == "tree"), by = "image.id") %>%
   select(image.id, image.tags = image.tags.x)
##   image.id image.tags
## 1     img1      house
## 2     img1     garden
## 3     img1        sky
## 4     img1       tree
## 5     img3      house
## 6     img3       tree
```

Comment: I think `image.data %>% separate_rows(image.tags)` is what I need, but I cannot get it to work with my data. No error, but also no change in the data frame. Any suggestions for how to do that without `%>%`?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the package and if you still have trouble the data you are running it on may have some difference relative to the data that was posted.